# Using type variable from declaration in function

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to Haskell and I'm trying to use a type variable from the function declaration in the creation (not quite sure what to call this in Haskell) of a record type.
As always, code explains my problem a lot better:

```
data S a = S {x::a}

f :: a -> S a
f n = (S a){x=n}
```

GHC says that a is not in scope on the last line. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: ghci seems to be happy with `f n = S {x=n}`

Comment: You are right, wow that was a simple solution. If you add this as an answer I will happily accept it. Feel like an idiot I didn't try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `f n = S {x=n}`, the type variable is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you *do* need the type variable from declaration, use the [scoped type variables](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) extension.

Comment: Somehow I cannot get a working example with ScopedTypeVariables. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @nponeccop What about the one in the documentation?